# Several appendix chapters after each part in book

Tags: appendices, parts

I have a plain latex document with `book` document class, which has several `\part`s. And I would like to organize my book in the following manner:

```
Part I
  Chapter 1
  Chapter 2
  Chapter 3
  Chapter* (unnumbered) Appendix A
Part II
  Chapter 1
  Chapter 2
  Chapter* (unnumbered) Appendix A
  Chapter* (unnumbered) Appendix B
Part III
  Chapter 1
  Chapter 2
  Chapter 3
  Chapter 4
  Chapter* (unnumbered) Appendix A
```

As you can see, I want to have an appendix for each part of my book. Each appendix may have one or more appendix chapters.

What I currently have is this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
    \part{One}
        \chapter{Ch One}
        \chapter{Ch Two}
        \chapter{Ch Three}
        \chapter*{Appendix A}
    \part{Two}
        \chapter{Ch One}
        \chapter{Ch Two}
        \chapter*{Appendix A}
        \chapter*{Appendix B}
    \part{Three}
        \chapter{Ch One}
        \chapter{Ch Two}
        \chapter{Ch Three}
        \chapter{Ch Four}
        \chapter*{Appendix A}
\end{document}
```

This works almost fine except for the headers. In the appendix pages, header shows the name of the last numbered chapter and section.

How can I make a true appendix for each part of my book? I would like a standard solution rather than a hack.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make use of the [`appendix`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/appendix) package.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

% To reset chapter counter for every part
\counterwithin*{chapter}{part}

% To reset appendix counter for every `appendices` environment
\renewcommand{\restoreapp}{}

\begin{document}
    \part{One}
        \chapter{Ch One}
        \chapter{Ch Two}
        \chapter{Ch Three}
      \begin{appendices}
        \chapter{Appendix A}
      \end{appendices}
    \part{Two}
        \chapter{Ch One}
        \chapter{Ch Two}
      \begin{appendices}
        \chapter{Appendix A}
        \chapter{Appendix B}
      \end{appendices}
    \part{Three}
        \chapter{Ch One}
        \chapter{Ch Two}
        \chapter{Ch Three}
        \chapter{Ch Four}
      \begin{appendices}
        \chapter{Appendix A}
      \end{appendices}
\end{document}
```